# Change cursor color and bottom line color in a Edit Text in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, textfield

I am making an application in android studio. My problem is that when you focus on the EditText, the bottom line and the cursor get red. I need to know if I can change that color. This is how i have the code of the EditText:

```
    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:ems="10"
        android:id="@+id/editText"
        android:layout_weight="1" />
```

Thank you!

Comment: Is red the accent color or primary color of your app?

Comment: you can change by using styles.

Comment: Oh man I'm new with this! I searched about that and i  finally could change the color. Thanks! @GSala

Comment: @SantiagoGlz Bonus: You can use the Theme Editor in Android Studio 1.4 to make it easier to manage the styles. Some info here: http://android-developers.blogspot.dk/2015/09/android-studio-14.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As commented above and for others to see, you can change the colorAccent in the main app theme/style